# Sharepoint 2013 client object model authentication

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-clientobject

I need to perform a Sharepoint 2013 client object model authentication.

http://vrdmn.blogspot.com.au/2013/01/authenticating-net-client-object-model.html

I'm using a shared hosting service (http://www.arvixe.com/) where the Sharepoint client assemblies are not installed.

how can i deploy the relevant client assemblies to the bin directory?

Comment: Are you sure that the hoster uses SP2013, and not SP2010?

Comment: what SP did you mean? they said that they don't have Sharepoint assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a redistributable which you can install on the hosted machine:

Just download the MSI from this link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Totally agree with you. But the link i posted is to download the MSI and not a blog which answers the question. Anyways, I have updated my answer to clarify the fact.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't deploy the Client DLL's, but only your own dll, you'll have to merge the client dll's into your own dll. You can do this by using a tool called [ilmerge.exe](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).
Hope this helps!